# Dynamically adding UserControls within a UserControl

Tags: wpf

I have a UserControl (UserControlA) that holds multiple other UserControls (UserControlBs), but I'd like that number to be dynamic.

Currently, the XAML for UserControlA looks like this:

**UserControlA.xaml**

```
<UserControl ...>
    <StackPanel>
        <local:UserControlB />
        <local:UserControlB />
        <local:UserControlB />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

And then UserControlA shows up, as expected, in MainWindow.xaml when I do this:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid>
        <controls:UserControlA />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

However, instead of being stuck with just 3 UserControlBs I'd like for that number to be dynamic based on an object I pass to it. Something like this...

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid>
        <controls:UserControlA UserControlBs="{Binding Path=UserControlBList}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And then, depending on how many UserControlBs there are, the UserControlBs are created and populate UserControlA.

Any good examples on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Since you're using `Binding`, the `UserControlBList` is a list of view models for the `UserControlB`'s `DataContext`?

Comment: Use an ItemsControl which has UserControlB in its ItemTemplate.